# XNA template for surface missing in Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xna, pixelsense

I installed Visual Studio 2010 and then installed VS service pack 1. After I installed GSE from [This link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714). After that I tried to create new project for surface but it didn't shown me XNA Template for it. It just displays me only one project template `Surface Application(WPF)` in surface->v2.0 tab

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the template by

1. Updating Visual Studio to SP1
2. Uninstall and re-installed `Surface SD 2.0`
3. Uninstall and re-installed XNA Game Studio Downloaded from [This Link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23714)

And it just started working